# Server response take time when same User open 2 same links

Tags: linux, mysql, php, performance

I am providing API service, My Site response is Fast, but when user open 2 same links at same time, then the server open the request and holds it from 20-50 seconds...

Using WHM-Apache, mySQL.

Diagnose response time with PHP code:

```
// Script Start
global $start_time_2;
$start_time_2 = microtime(true);
function shutdown()
{
    // This is our shutdown function,
    // here we can do any last operations before the script is complete.
    global $start_time_2;
    $time = microtime(true)-$start_time_2;
    echo "PHP Total Time at shutdown ".$time.' Sec';
}


$time_start = microtime(true);
// my code logic here
echo "Code Execution Time ".(microtime(true)-$time_start).' Sec';

//Script End
```

If user open 1 page at a time.

Output

```
Code Execution Time 0.02 Sec;
PHP Total Time at shutdown 0.022 Sec;
```

If user open 2 or more page at same time.

```
Code Execution Time 0.02 Sec;
PHP Total Time at shutdown 21.5 Sec;
```

Second Page response

```
Code Execution Time 0.02 Sec;
PHP Total Time at shutdown 33.5 Sec;
```

Sometimes user hits the same page in a loop, then my server go down, then it needs apache restart.

How can I manage these kinds of the issue?

Comment: What does the page do?

Comment: Page do some business logic, and get data from MYsql, and convert it into JSON then send to user.